# Use offline stylesheets in WevVIew

Tags: android, webview, css

I would like to use a temporary downloaded stylesheet if there is no internet connnection.

```
<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"MY_HREF">
```

If I use "href=file:///android_asset/stylesheet.css" it works with the packaged file, however that is not exchangeable.

I would like to use something like file:///data/data/cache/stylesheet.css. 
WebSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true) does not help.

I tried already content://my.authority/stylesheet.css and implemented my own ContentProvider for my.authority.

The ContentProvider implements openFile and is called by the WebView:
I have already checked, that the file really exists.

```
@Override
    public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        String path = uri.getEncodedPath();
        return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(new File(getContext().getCacheDir(), path), ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    }
```

This shows in the logs: "webview: Exception: content://my.authority/stylesheet.css

Any suggestions?